# Using Interfaces And DI In Yii Controllers

Tags: php, yii, interface, dependency-injection

I want to work with Interfaces and Dependency Injection in my Yii 1.1.14 project. Here is the demo code that I have:

The interface:

```
interface IUserInterface
{   
    public function DoSomething();
}
```

The class:

```
class UserService implements IUserInterface
{
    public function DoSomething()
    {
        echo "TEST TEST";
    }
}
```

Now comes the part that is problematic for me. How do I inject the interface in my controller?

I have tried this:

```
class AccountController extends Controller
{       
    protected $userService;

    public function __construct(IUserInterface $userInterface) 
    {
        $this->userService = $userInterface;

        parent::__construct();
    }    

    public function actionTest()
    {
        $this->userService->DoSomething();
    }
}
```

but this won't work, because of CController constructor:

```
public void __construct(string $id, CWebModule $module=NULL)
```

What should I do, so I can use the interface in my controller?

I asked the same question on the Yii forum, but we ended up going in circles: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/52810-using-interfaces-and-di-in-yii-controllers/

Comment: In Yii it is better to create your UserService as an ApplicationComponent and use it everywhere like this Yii::app()->userService without DI

Comment: Now, it can be done easily in Yii 2. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753235/how-to-use-dependency-injection-on-yii2

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to use dependency injection in Yii since the framework hasn't been created with the idea to use it.

There is one extension letting you use dependency Injection: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiipimple

I havn't tried it so I can't tell you if this extension is answering to your needs.

Comment: This doesn't look a lot like dependency injection, but rather like service location. You end up fetching things from the container, not injecting them in the controller.

Comment: Yeah, it's true. I think you can't perform real dependency injection in Yii whitout modifying the core of the framework. 
But I think this service locator is the best that you can get in Yii-1. You can have a separation of concerns by using it.

Comment: Agreed :) The only way to do otherwise is through extending the framework

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem with Zend Framework 1: the framework uses the constructor so you can't use it for dependency injection.

What I have done to integrate PHP-DI in ZF1 is I override the "Dispatcher" of the framework, that is the object which is responsible to create the controller.

By overriding it, I can control how the controller is created and thus inject dependencies.

Have a look here: https://github.com/mnapoli/PHP-DI-ZF1