# How to use Dependency Injection on Yii2

Tags: php, dependency-injection, yii2

I am new on Yii2 and I am trying to use **Dependency Injection**.

In my scenario a **Pedido** can have one **Servico** and a Servico has many Pedidos.  Here is the **Pedido** class model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "pedido".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $data
 * @property integer $servico_id
 *
 * @property Servico $servico
 */
class Pedido extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'pedido';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['data', 'servico_id'], 'required'],
            [['data'], 'safe'],
            [['servico_id'], 'integer']
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'data' => Yii::t('app', 'Data'),
            'servico_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Servico ID'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getServico()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Servico::className(), ['id' => 'servico_id']);
    }
}
```

Here is **Servico** model class

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "servico".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $descricao
 * @property string $valor
 * @property integer $quantidade
 *
 * @property Pedido[] $pedidos
 */
class Servico extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'servico';
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc

     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['descricao', 'valor'], 'required'],
            [['valor'], 'number'],
            [['quantidade'], 'integer'],
            [['descricao'], 'string', 'max' => 1000]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'descricao' => Yii::t('app', 'Descrição'),
            'valor' => Yii::t('app', 'Valor'),
            'quantidade' => Yii::t('app', 'Quantidade'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPedidos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pedido::className(), ['servico_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

In my **PedidoController** class I want to Inject the **Servico** class. I have created a **construtor** and changed the **actionCreate** in this way:

```
    <?php
    namespace app\controllers;

    use Yii; 
    use app\models\Pedido; 
    use app\models\Servico; 
    use app\models\PedidoSearch; 
    use yii\web\Controller; 
    use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException; 
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter; 
    use yii\di\Container;

    /** * PedidoController implements the CRUD actions for Pedido model. */  
  class PedidoController extends Controller {

    public Servico $servicoModel;

    public function __construct(Servico $servicoModel, $config = [])
    {
        $this->$servicoModel = $servicoModel;
        parent::__construct($config);
    }



    public function actionCreate()
    {

        $model = new Pedido();

        // 
        $container = new Container();
        $container->set('servico', 'app\models\Servico');
        $servicoModel = $container->get('servico');


        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    }
```

But when I got this error on the index action:

> PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException syntax error, unexpected
>   'Servico' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

at this line

> public Servico $servicoModel;

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with DI

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  How should I inject the Servico class in the PedidoController class ?

Answer (score 8):

Your mistake is not related with DI. The error is in this line: `public Servico $servicoModel;`. You wrote it in `Java` style, not `PHP`. Change to this:

```
public $servicoModel = null;
```

EDIT.

Change your `__construct` to  this:

```
public function __construct($id, $module, Servico $servicoModel, $config = [])
    {
        $this->servicoModel = $servicoModel;
        parent::__construct($id, $module, $config);
    }
```

Your errors:

1) `$this->$servicoModel` object property wrote `$this->VARIABLE_NAME`, no use `$` before VARIABLE_NAME.

2) In construct `controller` first and second parameters is `$id`, `$module`. See - https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Controller.php#L77

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I changed the line to `public $servicoModel = null;` as you said.  But now I am getting this error **PHP Recoverable Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Argument 1 passed to app\controllers\PedidoController::__construct() must be an instance of app\models\Servico, string given*  What should I do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.  The error is not happening anymore